# Return a 0 if no rows are found in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlhelper

I need your help with this query.

My table `CSO_EMP_ORG_DPM_VIE` has a column with different keys. Column name is `EXT_KEY`.

When I receive the same key number in `EXT_KEY`, I want the SQL code to count the duplicates using this query:

```
select EXT_KEY
from CSO_EMP_ORG_DPM_VIE
group by EXT_KEY
having count(*) > 1
```

This is working so far, but when it has **no** duplicate keys (numbers) in the column, I want it to generate it with 0 zero, and not nothing.

[image: No results in the query]

[image: changed having count to 0 for results]

[image: output with 3 same keys]

My expected result is; when two keys are the same I want to generate a 1. When no keys are the same, I want to generate an 0. Right now i got no result at all like in the screenshot.

How can I fix this SQL query accordingly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say Microsoft SQL, and tag <mysql> and <sqlhelper>. Which dbms are you actually using?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (no images). A.k.a.[mcve]

Comment: The picture for the query is from a MS SQL interface, so I think it may have been incorrectly tagged

Comment: just do select 0 from ... having count() > 1

Comment: @Se0ng11

like this? the count function need an argument it says.

select () from CSO_EMP_ORG_DPM_VIE group by EXT_KEY having COUNT () >1

Comment: Sorry, but this paragraph: *'This is working so far, but when it has duplicate keys (numbers) in the column, I want it to generate it with 0 zero, and not nothing.'* is confusing.  Could you clarify or give an example [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63410056/edit), please?

Comment: @Paul My expected result is; when two keys are the same, I want the query generate a 1. When no keys are the same, I want the query to generate an 0.The query is only working when i got dubble ext keys,

Comment: But right now it generates a list of duplicate keys. So it makes no sense to, if that list is empty, say you want a zero instead.

Comment: @underscore, correct, when the list is empty i want a zero instead

Comment: And what about when you have three or more keys the same?

Comment: @paul, i tested it with 3 same ext keys, my output is 1, screenshot added

Comment: I've posted an answer - you may find that part of it is appropriate for you.  The first answer could be used to give a result if you're simply checking to see if there are *any* duplicates whatsoever, but the first SQL example will tell you the counts of all distinct keys.

Comment: when u say if have more than 1, then u want to return 0, right? then `select 0 from table ... where count(1)> 1`, this will ensure when it find record count more than 1, it will return 0, else will be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression like this:

```
SELECT EXT_KEY,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END flag
FROM CSO_EMP_ORG_DPM_VIE
GROUP by EXT_KEY
```

or if you want 1 result for the table:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(EXT_KEY) > COUNT(DISTINCT EXT_KEY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END flag
FROM CSO_EMP_ORG_DPM_VIE
```

Comment: That looks considerably smoother than my version!  ;o)

Comment: thank you for the query, it show me now the complete list with all keys and 0. i only need one result 0 for the complete list. like in the screenshot "output with 3 same keys"

Comment: @HenkHadders check my 2nd query.

Comment: checked and works, thank you for your help, helps me al lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not blindingly obvious as to what you are asking for.  To that end, this query gives a 1/0 result based on having a count greater than 0 for each key...

```
SELECT   
    p.EXT_KEY, 
    EXT_KEY_RESULT = ISNULL((SELECT 1 
        FROM CSO_EMP_ORG_DPM_VIE c
        WHERE c.EXT_KEY = p.EXT_KEY 
        HAVING COUNT(EXT_KEY) > 0), 0)
FROM 
    CSO_EMP_ORG_DPM_VIE p
```

Alternatively, if you are looking to count each of the keys, you could try...

```
SELECT   EXT_KEY, COUNT(EXT_KEY)
FROM     CSO_EMP_ORG_DPM_VIE
GROUP BY EXT_KEY
```

It's always good practice to specify a particular field in the `COUNT` aggregate, particularly the primary key, as it's faster to reference.

You really need to give us an expected result for your requirements and be very clear about your expectations.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(EXT_KEY) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS dupes
FROM CSO_EMP_ORG_DPM_VIE
```

PLEASE NOTE: Credit here to forpas for providing a smoother answer which I have borrowed.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your quick reply, my expected result needs to be a single 0 with no ext_keys who are the same. When ext_keys are the same i recieve a single 1 like in the screenshot. Unfortunately is the query not giving a 0 when no dubble entrys are in the table.I only need one result number, that would be a 0 or 1. no dubble keys or dubble keys

Comment: @HenkHadders - Do you not care which key is being repeated?

Comment: no not necessary, it is for our monitoring. After a 1 is given I will check the list for further analyse

Comment: got the sql working from forpas, thank you for your support :-)